# register large buffer for RDMA in Linux kernel module

Tags: kernel-module, rdma

i'm a newbie experimenting a project using rdma (ib_verbs) in kernel module. I got the example code from krping and tinkering on it. The system run on 64bits Linux  Centos with a custom 3.10 Linux kernel that require transparent huge pages disabled.
I want a large (4GB up) of RDMA read/write able space which doesn't have to be contiguous as i'll most likely write/read at most 1MB at a time from remote party (random access).

Question:

1. Should i just do a thousand times of 4MB kmalloc and register DMA region? How bad it is, design wise for allocating large chuck of memory using kmalloc instead of vmalloc? I heard it should not be done and large memory should only retrieved via vmalloc. But addresses from vmalloc are not good for DMA.
2. If not then what would be a good alternative way to have a 4GB buffer that can be random access from remote party?
3. How does user-space rdma manage this kind of buffer? I remembered that i only malloc 4GB of memory and call ibv_reg_mr and it is ready to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you're not using a memory that covers the entire physical memory (which isn't recommended for write-enabled MRs), you should use the `IB_WR_REG_MR` work request to register your memory region. For that, you would use the [`ib_map_mr_sg`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.11.7/source/drivers/infiniband/core/verbs.c#L1837) function which accepts a scatterlist and a page size. So basically, you can register an MR that is built with chunks of a fixed size that you choose.

There's a tradeoff here: using small allocation size will allow the kernel to find free memory easier on fragmented systems, but on the other hand it could decrease performance, as it can increase the load on the NIC's IOTLB.

User-space handles large MR registration by calling `get_user_pages` and using the system's page size (normally 4kb). Though some drivers have optimizations to try and detect larger page sizes internally, if the user-space memory happens to align that way.